Change the default size of Emacs frames in Emacs Snap
I am running Emacs 29.3 in Fedora (installed via Snap). There are two icons by default: Emacs and Emacs(Client). When I try to open an Emacs(Client) windows, I get tiny small frames to the left of the screen, despite changing these settings:
(setq initial-frame-alist
      '((top . 1)
    (left . 500)
    (width . 95)
    (height . 55)))

(setq default-frame-alist
      '((top . 1)
    (left . 500)
    (width . 95)
    (height . 55)))

The frames stay the same. I would like them to open in the same position but full length of the screen and twice the size.
The link below provides and example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pw2DMt6hQrJTdyXYHhUdGB9NfOIHBGD-/view?usp=sharing

As a thought, maybe it has something to do with Gnome on Wayland in this case not taking the size hints into account…

A workaround to this problem was adding this to my init file: (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Fira Code Nerd Font-13")). This had the effect of normalizing the frames.

If that helped, you might want to self-answer your question, so if somebody stumbles upon same problem they would try your solution out.

I feel my comment is more a workaround than a solution.
